# Internet Explorer just doesn't work at all.. css/js rendering wrong.. advice

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am redesigning a webpage for a club I am in.

After a lot of work, I have finally got it looking reasonably good (IMO) in Chrome, Firefox, etc.

Internet Explorer however is rendering everything completely wrong.

See: http://nationalstudentrodeo.org.uk/2012a/

The novo slide does not load, the mousover menu is not positioned correctly, all images are seemingly shrunk, and all the transparent images are not transparent.

Could anyone possibly link to specific resources re these problems - why is IE so tempremental...

Cheers

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing with? you may be using features which are not supported in older versions of IE, which would explain why things aren't working. You should also check that IE isn't going into quirksmode, because that's the No.1 reason for most of the kind of things your describing.

Comment: I am using IE 8. Others have tried in IE7 and had similar problems.. I believe I have fixed the quirksmode problem - still the same problems..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than the fact that IE is inept to begin with, you have comments and other things before the doctype. This puts IE into quirks mode. Remove all that to get IE to attempt to perform like the other far more modern browsers.

Comment: and validate the html/css,it seems that there are some unclosed tags

Comment: I have validated my html and css3 - it now passes, but the problems still persist. The three main problems are the mouseover menu not positioning correctly, the non transparency of images, and nivoslider not working.. Any advice appreciated. Thanks

Comment: IE<9 has problems with transparency. Haven't looked at it yet. You used the transitional doctype. New web pages have no use for that. Always use strict.

Comment: You still have the comments on the pages. Can't help till you remove them.

Comment: I have removed all comments.. and have changed the doctype to strict. The same problems are still present. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the problem on the main page. I do see it on the linked pages but, there, you still have the comments.

Comment: I am editing only the index page for now.. until i have fixed it, then i'll sort the interior pages.. Using IE 8, the top mouse over menu is out of position, no images are transparent, and the nivoslider does not work..? Are you using a different version?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4026/discussion-between-thomas-clowes-and-rob)

Answer (score -1):

If you're worried about how IE looks I would suggest that you design in IE and when you get it to look good in that then go over and look at it in Firefox, etc. It is a lot easier to get something that looks good in IE to look the same in Firefox then the other way around.

Comment: Never, EVER do that. It's like using a broken calculator to check your math first. Always, ALWAYS use a modern browser (ANYTHING but IE) to check your work first. Then and only then look at IE to see how badly it screws things up. But the multitude of bugs and quirks in IE are well known, as are the hacks to fix it. This way your code is most likely to work in all the modern browsers and you only have to hack your code for one: Internet Explorer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but IE IS a modern browser and it still has almost 55% of the market, hell 15% of users still use IE7 or IE6. So let's just ignore half the world because you feel like its an inferior browser. All I'm saying is that it is easier from a design perspective to get things looking good in the place that causes most problems.

Comment: Market share does not equate to modernism. Using a browser that mis-renders and mis-places elements, if it can handle it at all, is most likely to cause you to write non-standard or hacky code. My point is you should write proper code in the first place and test it in the most standards compliant browser you can find; and that browser is NEVER Internet Explorer. And a browser that can't handle a large portion of what other browsers can handle does not qualify IE as modern.  http://people.mozilla.com/~prouget/ie9/

Comment: And where do you get that I said to ignore IE? We have to make our sites work in IE and charge our clients the extra hours to do so!

Comment: I do not use IE normally, so I do not want to design in it. I am simply trying to make the site cross-compatible. Thanks

Comment: The fact that IE has such a large share of the market, standards compliant or not, means that you have no choice but to design for it. The simple fact of the matter is that you CAN write proper code and have it look just fine in IE9. When you compare Gecko and Trident side by side, there is little difference with regards to CSS2 support. CSS3 support is sketchy across the board. I'm talking IE9 to FF/Chrome, not IE7 or IE6. It may have taken IE longer to support a lot of CSS properties, but the gap is closing. If versions of IE below 9 disappeared today, so would the need for most IE hacks.

Comment: @ThomasClowes  When you design web sites that can potentially be viewed by anyone in the world, you should design for the largest segment of the population. Currently the largest segment of the population uses Internet Explorer and views web pages at 1024x768 resolution. Just because I view my pages in Firefox at 1920x1080 and everything looks fine to me, doesn't mean that people viewing the sites I design will have the same experience.

Comment: Barry - I understand that - hence why I am trying to fix the aforementioned problems. Thanks

Comment: @BarryFranklin - Absolutely false! That is what gets developers into trouble in the first place. You design to standards and NEVER to browsers. And while IE is closing the gap with CSS3, they are falling behind in almost every other category and always have.

Comment: @BarryFranklin - Please read my previous post that I forgot to tag with your name. I never said you should ignore IE.